# Camera crashing on Motorola Razr - Out Of Memory

Tags: android, android-camera, out-of-memory, motorola-droid

My app requires that I take a picture, and the only device I'm running in problems with is the Motorola Razr. I've tried it on the Nexus One, Droid X, Droid 2, Sensation, and a few others. Here is the code I am using:

```
public class CameraView extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraView";

  private SurfaceView preview=null;
  private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;
  public Camera camera=null;
  private boolean inPreview=false;
  private ImageView takePicture;

  private Uri uriTarget;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cameraview);

    takePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.take_picture);

    preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
    previewHolder=preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder
        .setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        uriTarget = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("uriTarget");
    }

    preview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            takePicture.setEnabled(false);
            camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);

        }

    });


    takePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
            camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, 
                    myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
            inPreview=false;    
        }

    });


  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try{
        if (camera==null) {
          camera=Camera.open();
          camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
          Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters(); 
          params.set("rotation", 90); 
          params.setJpegQuality(60);
          //params.setPictureSize(32, 32);
          camera.setParameters(params);

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        finish();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (inPreview) {
      camera.stopPreview();
    }
    if(camera != null)
        camera.release();
    camera=null;
    inPreview=false;

    super.onPause();
  }

  SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
      }
      catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("PictureDemo-surfaceCallback",
            "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
        Toast.makeText(CameraView.this, t.getMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
        int format, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        parameters.setJpegQuality(60);
        parameters.set("rotation", 90);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();

        inPreview=true;
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      // no-op
    }
  };


  ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {

        }};


  PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

        }};

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera1) {


            Constants.car_image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);  
            Constants.showImage = true;

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {


                File esd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


                File newDirectory = new File(esd.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/statefair/");
                if(!newDirectory.exists())
                    newDirectory.mkdirs();
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(esd.getAbsolutePath() + String.format(
                        "/DCIM/statefair/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));

                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                  System.out.println("IO exception");
            } finally {
                  System.out.println("Finally");
                  camera.release();
            }

            finish();

        }
        };
        AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback(){

           @Override
           public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            takePicture.setEnabled(true);
            }
         };
       protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
            outState.putParcelable("uriTarget", uriTarget);
        }
}
```

I get an outOfMemory error on this line:

```
Constants.car_image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

even when I set the JPEG quality to 10. Anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: It is because each phone has different camera image format, try to figure out what is the image format for motorola-droid and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

Full size images take a lot of memory, you should make re-size. Just for quick test, try this:

```
Options opts = new Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 4;        
Constants.car_image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);
```